# MYSQL Email Validation with Regex not working

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

i just want to fetch the invalid email addresses from my database, i tried with the following query, but its not working

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email!='' and email NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$'");
```

And the invalid Email is **a.bcdefg-3@abccom**

Comment: What happens now, no results returned or an error? Can you provide a bad email you'd expect this to find?

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: its returned no result and the invalid email is a.bcdefg-3@abccom

Comment: Maybe use something like that: [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Richard answer is correct however, it may not works given the collation used.
Therefore, if you have a case sensitive collation, you may want to lowercase your field.

Try this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `email` NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]._%-\+]+@[[:alnum:].-]+[.][[:alnum:]]{2,4}$';
```

I have updated the regex to use character classes instead of character range to avoid lower (or upper) case transformation.

Moreover, in some IDE, you may have to escape "." with two backslashes, therefore I use

```
[.]
```

instead of escaped dot.

I updated again to allow subdomains.
Edited to allow `+`, thanks to @Charlie Brumbaugh comment.

Comment: its working for the email a.bcdefg-3@abccom but it also fetching the valid email address abc.Abc@cd.eff.com

Comment: abc.Abc@cd.eff.com is a valid email address. If you really need to test the email domain/subdomain validity, don't do it through mysql.

Comment: i just want to fetch the invalid email address but it fetching the valid email address also

Comment: You're correct, check the last edit, it should work !

Comment: thanks man..finally its working..can you please tell me why mine is not working

Comment: Your regex was invalid at least because of the case. Moreover, the dot escaping may be wrong with your editor, that's why I chose to use [.] instead of \.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had the same problem and was looking for a solution for 2 hours.

Comment: This doesn't let users have the plus sign + in their emails. An adjusted regex would be REGEXP  '^[[:alnum:]._%-\+]+@[[:alnum:].-]+[.][[:alnum:]]{2,4}$'

Comment: thanks, @CharlieBrumbaugh, I've updated the regex given your comment.

Comment: So now it doesn't let users have - in the their emails, which is valid so long as its not the first character an updated one is ^[[:alnum:]._%-\+]+[[:alnum:]._%-\+-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+[.][[:alnum:]]{2,4}$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `email` NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

Works for my.

> Furthermore, do not use the **MySQL driver** as it is deprecated in PHP.

Comment: Is it working in phpMyAdmin/Adminer? Are you sure that there is an invalid entry?

Comment: its not working in phpMyAdmin and pls find the screenshot of the row

Comment: @Ezhil: Try the edited RegEx. You should validate the email address at input time and it should not be allowed to insert a invalid email address in database. This is not consistent.